# Twig use constant as attribute

Tags: twig

I want to pass constant as an attribute in the twig template.

Code looks like this: 
`{% if presenter.hasErrors(constant('Admin\App\ViewPresenters\EditorPresenter::FORM_ERRORS') )%}` and it throwing error `Message: Argument 1 passed to Admin\App\ViewPresenters::hasErrors() must be of the type string, null given, called in /vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php on line 1527`, as far as I understand twig did not recognize it's an constant. Is there any wat to pass constant in twig as an argument?

Comment: yeah thank you! You can create ansser and I'l up vote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `twig` a backslash is used to escape special characters e.g. `{{ '\'' }}` will output `'`. So to create a litteral backslash in `twig` you need to "escape" the backslash

```html
{{ constant('Admin\\App\\ViewPresenters\\EditPresenter::FORM_ERRORS') }}
```

---

You can see the difference in the outputted source code `twigfiddle`:

```html
{{ constant('Admin\App\ViewPresenters\EditPresenter::FORM_ERRORS') }}
```

*PHP source*

```php
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, twig_constant("AdminAppViewPresentersEditorPresenter::FORM_ERRORS"), "html", null, true);
```

```html
{{ constant('Admin\\App\\ViewPresenters\\EditorPresenter::FORM_ERRORS') }}
```

*PHP source*

```php
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, twig_constant("Admin\\App\\ViewPresenters\\EditorPresenter::FORM_ERRORS"), "html", null, true);
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/44ivh4)